# .net core 3.1 with swagger/swashbuckler without controller attributes

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle, .net-core-3.1

Anyone know how to configure swagger when using endpoint routing?

I see the following but no code on how to configure it.
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/issues/1306

The issue is without the following on my controller swagger doesn't find it.

```
[Route("[controller]")]
```

Also if there are multiple endpoints with the same HttpMethod it pukes. I have to define the route attribute on there too. I don't want to have to do this. Dev's will forget.

```
[Route("[controller]/MyGetRoute")]
```

Is there a configuration at the app level to just follow the endpoint routing convention?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use conventional based routing. If so, try the [Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConventionalRouting](https://github.com/chsakell/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.ConventionalRouting) package instead, which is an extension on top of Swashbuckle and supports conventional routing as well.